# Hiding namespace in method names in a Doxygen doc

Tags: doxygen

I use Doxygen to generate a reference guide for a large C++ API with several namespaces.

The namespace name is added to each variable or method name in the class documentation page. For example for a class such as `MyNamespace::MyClass`, Doxygen generates a page where each method is documented as follows:

```
MyNameSpace::MyClass::MyEnum MyNameSpace::MyClass::getSomeType()
```

I would like to reduce the clutter and have:

```
MyClass::MyEnum MyClass::getSomeType()
```

Any hints?

Comment: I think what you want to do is set `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES` to `YES` in your configuration file.